# How can I make jekins recognise my python install?

Tags: python, windows, jenkins

In order for me to run a python script as a build step in Jenkins I add the following to "Execute windows batch command":

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:\jenkins\p4v\main\BuildHelpers\HelloTest.py
```

Why do I have to pass the `python.exe` path for this to work? In a normal command window I don't have to do this as `C:\Python27` is in my Path setting (both for user and system).

What `PATH` does jenkins use? How can I add to it?

Answer (score 1):

It should work as long as your Python is in your system PATH. However, have you restarted the machine since adding it? I've found that this is necessary when making changes to slave nodes' environment variables--Jenkins won't notice the changes until the machine is restarted and the slave node reconnected.

Comment: I tried the reboot, still the same - jenkins gets stuck at the step if I don't provide the python path. BTW I'm a jenkins novice, what does "slave node" mean? Is it related do you think? Thanks